# React native app performance on connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, mapstatetoprops, mapdispatchtoprops

I'm creating react native app with redux state management. I want to know what is the best practice of having connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps).

I have several component classes i.e. ParentA, ChildA, ChildB. Currently I'm getting state properties for each parent and child classes independently.

eg:

```
const ParentA = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.item.name}</Text>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { item } = state

  return {
    item: item.item,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ParentA)
```

```
const ChildA = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { item } = state

  return {
    item: item.item,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChildA)
```

```
const ChildB = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.item.age}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { item } = state

  return {
    item: item.item,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChildB)
```

But rather having `connect` for each child component I could get `item` state from `ParentA` and pass it to `Child` components.

eg:

```
const ParentA = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.item.name}</Text>
      <ChildA item={item}/>
      <ChildB item={item}/>
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { item } = state

  return {
    item: item.item,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ParentA)
```

```
const ChildA = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { item } = state

  return {
    item: item.item,
  }
}

export default ChildA
```

```
const ChildB = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.item.age}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { item } = state

  return {
    item: item.item,
  }
}

export default ChildB
```

My questions are,

1. What would be the best approach while considering the app performance ?
2. Can I use same approach for `mapDispatchToProps` as well ?

Comment: Feel to free you can read about it here : https://www.samdawson.dev/article/react-redux-use-selector-vs-connect

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can Use `useSelector, useDispatch` but the thing is you should use hooks. It can fix considering the app performance with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than using 'const', try another datatypes such as 'var' or 'let' as 'const' value once fixed cannot be changed.